# BootStrap Jumbotron expands the Navbar, and is not separate

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Lately I've been following a lot of tutorials on how to build my own website with Bootstrap. I have pretty good knowledge of HTML, but not of CSS, which is why I want to create a website using Bootstrap.

My problem: I got my navbar created at the top, and when I added in a jumbotron, it basically added it into the Navbar, which is not what I wanted at all.

Here is the code http://pastebin.com/x7UTEjJz
And here is what I'm talking about when I say it expands into the Navbar:

http://prntscr.com/3mj578

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without seeing a live example / your own css.

Comment: So I got a version running on jsfiddle... but it doesn't seem to change wether you have the jumbotron or not... http://jsfiddle.net/sSx2P/

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the desired result is? :)

Comment: You have successfully replicated what I'm getting! I want to add padding of some sort to separate the jumbotron from the top navbar. As of right now the jumbotron is in the navbar, and I do not want that. I want the jumbotron to be outside the navbar.

Comment: The black around the jumbotron (part of the navbar) is not what I want, I want the navbar to be separate from the jumbotron if that helps clear it up

Comment: Nathan is correct. :) Add another close div just after <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li></ul></div>

Comment: As a side note. You should spend some time cleaning up your code. There are spaces (between attributes and their definitions) that shouldn't be there, and the indentation is incredibly confusing. It would make it much easier for yourself and others to spot mistakes like closing elements if it was nicely indented. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div` containing the jumbotron class is inside your nav `div`. You need to make sure you close all your `div`s for the nav (and its sub-elements) before you add your `div` for the jumbotron (there are two missing closing `div`s right now).

Also, if you're using a fixed nabvar, then you need to add padding to your `body` to scoot the content below the fixed navbar ([ref](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment)).

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napple/PrR53/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it must have been an easy fix! I'll try to learn more from my mistakes, I thought that I had the Div's closed! Thanks again!